# Закономерность ряда

Tags: алгоритм, циклы

Помогите определить закономерность ряда для цикла: 3,6,9,13,16,19,23,26,29.

Нужно для решения задачи: http://smotr.im/b5we

Comment: закономерность-то очевидна, а что вам нужно сделать с этим рядом?

Comment: @VladD, судя по меткам - написать цикл для генерации таких чисел :)

Comment: @Flammable: добавил версию на C#

Comment: Ссылка на задачу не работает (прошло почти 3 года). Для поиска закономерности преобразование Фурье не поможет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js версия

```
var numerator = function(maxN){
  var i = 0;
  var result = [];
  do{
    result.push(i+3, i+6, i+9);
    i += 10;
  }while((i+9 <= maxN))
  return result;
};
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/rXnXz/)

а сама задача как я понял среднее арифметическое посчитать для данного ряда, если учесть [Среднее арифметическое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5) - сумма всех членов поделенное на количество, исходя из того, что мы определили что ряд комбинация 3 чисел, увеличивается по арифметической прогрессии шагом 10, мы можем далее  3,6,9,13,16,19,23,26,29 => 3,13,23,6,16,26,9,19,29 => вспоминаем математику S = S1 + S2 + S3 где S общая сумма элементов S1,S2,S3 
если вспомним что Sn = ((2a1 + (n-1)*d)/2 )*n - где d шаг, а1 - первый член, n- количество элементов S1 = ((2*3 + (3-1)*10)/2)*3 = 39 и т.д. для других таким образом функция для посчета среднего арифметического  для данной последовательности (js)

```
var srSred = function(items){    
    var len = items.length / 3;        
    var result = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        result += ((2 * items[0] + ((len - 1)* 10))/2)*len;
    result = result / items.length; 
    return result;   
}
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/PL7Br/)

Answer (score 6):

```
3  | 6  | 9
13 | 16 | 19
23 | 26 | 29
33 | 36 | 39
43 | 46 | 49
```

В общем идет прибавка +10 к числовому ряду.

Answer (score 4):

В виде кода:

```
const int max = 9000;
for (int i = 3, c = 0; i <= max; ++c, i += (c % 3 == 0) ? 4 : 3)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

закономерность тут в том, что этот ряд заполнен числами, последний десятичный разряд которых кратен трем

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку вы не указали язык, вот вам на C#:

```
public IEnumerable<BigInteger> GenerateSequence()
{
    BigInteger tens = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return tens + 3;
        yield return tens + 6;
        yield return tens + 9;
        tens += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: По предыдущим вопросам топикстартера таки видно, что его интересует С++.

Answer (score 0):

не С++ а РНР, этот вопрос в Курсах Русакова

---

```
<?php
$x = 0;
for ($a = 1; $a < 4; $a++)
{$x =$x + 3;
$sum = $sum + $x;
if ($a == 3)
{$x = $x + 4;
$sum = $sum + $x;
}}
for ($a = 5; $a < 7; $a++)
{$x =$x + 3;
$sum = $sum + $x;
if ($a == 6)
{$x = $x + 4;
$sum = $sum + $x;
}}
for ($a = 7; $a < 9; $a++)
{$x =$x + 3;
$sum = $sum + $x;}
echo $sum = $sum / $a;
?>
```

Comment: Да уж. Если это из курсов Рысакова, то вывод один: Рускова -- давить. Урод однозначно. (Если такого в его курсах нет -- готов извиниться)

Comment: @alexlz, судя по содержимому сайта (по ссылке ТС) справедливо Ваше первое утверждение.

Просто удивительно, ну как одним не лень писать такую дурь, а другим ее изучать?

Comment: @avp времена напёрсточников давно прошил. Вот и приходится пацанам курсы мастрячить.

Comment: Задание из его курса, решение нет.
если знаете хороший способ изучить РНР Посоветуйте буду признателен.

Comment: @wan_no, нельзя начинать изучение программирования с ПХП (даже по лучшим учебникам).

Здесь, на ХК, это многократно обсуждалось. Посмотрите через гугл

    site:hashcode.ru обучение с чего начать

или сделайте похожие запросы. Почитайте (в т.ч. комментарии), подумайте. 

Если вопросы останутся -- задавайте их.

--

А Ваш ответ - разве он отвечает на вопрос ТС? Код с ошибкой (в 5-й строке $sum еще не определена). Даже если ее исправить, напечатает какое-то одно число.

Что оно означает?

Или Вы думаете, что все будут изучать этот код, дабы разгадать, а *что именно* он должен делать?

Comment: Благодарю за совет!!!
А код должен вывести среднее арифметическое от 3 6 9 13 16 19 23 26 29

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи из курса Русакова по PHP:

```
$sred=0;
$n=3;
$j=0;
$f=0;

for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++){
    $f = $n*$i+$j;
    if($i%$n==0)
    $j++;

    echo $f;
    echo "<br />";

    $sred = $sred + $f;
}
$sred = $sred/$i;
echo "Среднее значение = $sred";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильный ответ, и как видишь, я пользовался только тем, о чем было рассказано раньше. Причем здесь действительно высчитывается сумма последовательности. Можешь проверить увеличив условие цикла до 40 или 50. Ничего сложного. На боевых сайтах все будет гораздо сложнее. Так что привыкай...

<?php

echo "<b>Среднее арифметическое последовательности:</b><br />
    <b>3, 6, 9, 13, 16, 19, 23, 26, 29</b><br /><br />";

```
$total = 0;

$count = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
{
    if($i == 1)
    {
        $total += 3;

        $count++;

        $total += 6;

        $count++;

        $total += 9;

        $count++;
    }
    elseif($i % 10 == 0)
    {
        $total = $total + $i + 3;

        $count++;

        $total = $total + $i + 6;

        $count++;

        $total = $total + $i + 9;

        $count++;
    }
    else
        continue;
}

$average = $total / $count;

echo "Средне-арифметическое равно: $average";
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Написал вот такой вариант в PHP. Я чайник, но понимаю что этот код неправильный ввиду того что я ввел числа 12 и 22, а чем их можно заменить, не меняя существенно этот код - не понимаю! Помогите, братцы!)

```
$e = 0;
$i = 0;
$sum = 0;
while (true) {
    $e+=3;
    if ($e > 29) break;
    if ($e % 12 == 0) $e++ ;
    if ($e % 22 == 0) $e++ ;
    $sum += $e;
    $i++;

    }
echo "<br/>Результат: ".$sum/$i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я прекрасно знаю, что решение не оптимально. Все оптимальные уже разобрали. ;) Зато мое решение буквально копирует условие задачи. С эдакой детской непосредственностью. *:P

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 30; ++i ) {
        switch( i % 10 ) {
            case 3:
            case 6:
            case 9: sum += i; n++;
        }
    }

    printf("sum = %d\nn = %d\navg = %f\n", sum, n, (double)sum / (double)n);

    return 0;
}
```